# SonataAdmin - Breadcrumbs

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using `SonataAdminBundle` and I'm seeing some odd things with the breadcrumbs

On some I see `Dashboard / User list / Bob` when editing a user called Bob

Now when I edit another entity, such as `Post` for a Post Entity, I see things like the following

`Dashboard / Post list / BM\AdminBundle\Entity\Post:000000002e991893000000000df3fcde`

Has anyone seen this before?

I'm not sure why it is doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the __toString() function in your Entity, for instance :

```
//in BM\AdminBundle\Entity\Post
public function __toString()
{
    if ($this->getId())
        return "Post ".$this->getId();
    return "New Post";
}
```

Comment: Here is the doc [Troubleshooting] http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to define magic function __toString() in respective entity and return one property as string.